# Android Webview using physical units (cm/in)

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I would like to display an image in a webview with a defined width and height.

When i set my html to:`<img src='img.png' width='100%' height='100cm' />`
When displayed: the height never get to 100cm or whatever I choose.

I tried playing with viewport and scale but did not manage to have my image display in the rights physical units.

Here is my activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class myActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ruler);
        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String url = "image.png";

        String imgSrcHtml = "<html><img src='" + url
                + "' width='100%' height='100cm' /></html>";
        web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", imgSrcHtml,
                "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    }
}
```

And the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    " >


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Have you any idea?

Comment: try Setting height for webview instead.

Comment: I already tried with setting the webview layout_height to '1000mm' and image height to 100%. Doesn't work.

Comment: try giving height in double quote height="100cm"

Comment: can you post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this embedding my webview in a linearlayout with the fixed size and a scrollview!

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000mm" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000mm"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```